# lightning controller get string value

Tags: lightning, substring

using substringAfter and substringBefore in lightning component controller but string value i am not able to get and it is throwing an error that substringAfter and substringBefore is not a method.

```
  var recUrl = 'CF00N4A00000CMi5V=04612373&CF00N4A00000CMi5V_lkid=003D000003s6tsS&';
  var recid = recUrl.substringAfter('CF00N4A00000CMi5V_lkid=').substringBefore('&');
```

I want this value **003D000003s6tsS** this record id is not hardcoded if i'll open another record this id value will change so whatever value after this **CF00N4A00000CMi5V_lkid=** and before **&** need to store in var in lightning controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not method of [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object in Javascript. They are mothods of Apex [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).
You could use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
const recUrl = 'CF00N4A00000CMi5V=04612373&CF00N4A00000CMi5V_lkid=003D000003s6tsS&';
const guard = 'CF00N4A00000CMi5V_lkid=';
let recId = recUrl.substring(recUrl.indexOf(guard) + guard.length);
recId = recId.substring(0, recId.indexOf('&'));
console.log(recId); // 003D000003s6tsS
```

By the way, consider using `let` and `const` instead of `var`. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#declarations)